# How to add a modified button in Android app

Tags: java, android, android-view

```
public class NoteActivity extends Activity {
```

define db:

```
static String TABLE_NAME="Notes";
 static String ID="_id";
 static String DATE="date";
 static String NOTE="note";
 static String[] COLUMNS = { ID, DATE, NOTE };     
 static int[] TO = { android.R.id.hint, android.R.id.text1, 
                     android.R.id.text2};
 long selectedIndex = 0;
 DBConnection dbconn;
```

onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);       
    OnClickListener OnInsertClick=null;
    OnClickListener OnDeleteClick=null;
    dbconn=new DBConnection(this);       
    show(); 
    OnInsertClick=new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
```

get the datePicker date:

```
      DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.dp); 
      String date = dp.getYear()+"/"+
      (dp.getMonth()+1)+"/"+dp.getDayOfMonth();
      String note = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.note)).getText().toString();
      insert( date, note);
      ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.note)).setText("");
      }       
    };     
    Button insert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.insert);
    insert.setOnClickListener(OnInsertClick);
    OnDeleteClick = new OnClickListener(){
       public void onClick(View v) {
       delete(selectedIndex);
      }
    };
    Button delete=(Button)findViewById(R.id.delete);
    delete.setOnClickListener(OnDeleteClick);

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
        selectedIndex = id;
        }
     });
}
```

listview

```
private void show() {
 SQLiteDatabase db=dbconn.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c=null;
    c=db.query(TABLE_NAME, COLUMNS,null, null, null, null, null);     
 SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c, COLUMNS, TO);
 ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
 lv.setAdapter(adapter);


 startManagingCursor(c);

 db.close();
}
```

insert button

```
private void insert(String date, String note) {
  ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
  values.put(DATE,date);
  values.put(NOTE,note);
  SQLiteDatabase db = dbconn.getWritableDatabase();
  db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
  db.close();
  show();
}
```

delete button

```
private void delete(long id) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = dbconn.getWritableDatabase();
  db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id=?" , new String[]{Long.toString(id)});
  db.close();
  show();
  }
}
```

I would like to add a modified button, when I click listview, you can directly change the contents of listview.

Comment: `a modified button` how exactly is the button modified? Show how you modified it.

Comment: I want the function is that when I press Listview, he displays the data in the TextView and then changes the TextView's data after clicking the modifier will be uploaded back to SQLite and displayed on the Listview